# getting negative values of latitude and longitude

Tags: android, android-location

I want to get the values of longitude and latitude in my app and I have done that but the issue is Iam getting the negative symbol with values.Values are correct though but dont know why getting the negative sign with the values.

Code of java class :

```
package com.vshine.neuron.testing;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class code extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView textView;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_code);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         // TODO: Consider calling
         //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
         // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
         //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
         //                                          int[] grantResults)
         // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
         // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
         return;
         }
         Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
         onLocationChanged(location);
         }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        textView.setText("Longitude: " + longitude + "\n\n" + "Latitude: " + latitude);

        }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
        }
```

Comment: Latitude and longitude coordinates can take on negative values, see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578799.aspx), for example, which discusses this.  No, your code isn't broken.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Issue is  Iam not getting the mylocation when I put these LatLong means Iam not getting the correct LatLong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **`Latitude` and `Longitude` can have negative values.**

Your code is fine

[Check any ref](https://www.quora.com/What-does-negative-longitude-mean)

Comment: Issue is Iam not getting the mylocation when I put these LatLong means Iam not getting the correct LatLong?

Comment: Did your device location is enable ?

Comment: Iam testing this on computer emulator

Comment: From the Emulator Settings. You can set the desired latitude and longitude. While using in Emulator. You won't get the current location. You will get the location which has been set in settings

Comment: I tried to run it on my mobile phone but it only give me the screen with Location written on it(Location is the Hint I have given to the textview in my xml code)

Comment: I got the issue 
Thanku for your help.

Comment: How you solved your issue. Please post it so that others with same problem will get help.

Answer (score 1):

Latitude designates North and South of the Equator. Longitude designates East and West of the Prime Meridian.

A negative latitude means South of the Equator, and a negative longitude means West of the Prime Meridian.

Location data is often represented in the form of latitude and longitude pairs like below:

37.427619, -122.166972
[Hoover Tower, Stanford University]

The simple framework below can help you decode the location pairs.

```
+ + : North and East 
+ - : North and West 
- - : South and West 
- + : South and East
```

Note that the centerpoint for this framework is 0,0 where the Prime Meridian and the Equator intersect, in the Gulf of Guinea.

Answer taken from Quora. [Quora Link](https://www.quora.com/What-does-negative-longitude-mean)

Comment: Can you please tell what should I change in my code to get the positive values?

Answer (score 0):

`LatLong` could be positive as well as negative.

Example: 
`44.389061321549, -114.659369144245` is a valid `LatLong` of Idaho state in USA.

Just copy your LatLong and paste it in the search box of [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps), you will get your exactly location of LatLong.

Comment: Thats what the issue Iam not getting the mylocation when I put these LatLong

Comment: What LatLong you are getting?

Comment: -34.7868114 , -55.2337042

Comment: If you are running app on Emulator, this could be the default `LatLong` in your emulator setting -> Location

Comment: default values are different in my emulator I have already checked those